# Microphone only working for one Ubuntu user in Skype

Tags: sound, xubuntu, skype, users, microphone

I've had problems with Skype for a bit, but managed to fix some of them (using Skype from the repos to make it work with Pulseaudio, fixing cracking sounds as described in [a blog post on itbubbles](http://itbubbles.wordpress.com/2013/10/21/xubuntu-13-10-sound-issues-skype-distorted-microphone-crackling-sound-indicator-disabled/)).

Now I have a rather odd problem: I have different Ubuntu accounts for work and private, and Skype works fine in my work account, but in my private user account, the microphone doesn't work. I think I did the last Skype reinstallation on the work account.

The microphone works well in other apps, but only silence in Skype (although I can hear the other side just fine). But the Skype recording does seem to transmit system sounds (Skype notification sounds are recorded/transmitted).

I tried with a clean Skype profile (dumping the `~/.Skype` directory), but no effect. I'm on XUbuntu 13.10, Skype 4.2.0.11.

Any ideas?

What settings could be saved user-specifically? Access right issues? User-specific audio settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"The microphone works well in other apps, but only silence in Skype (though I can hear the other side just fine). But the Skype recording does seem to transmit system sounds (Skype notification sounds are recorded/transmitted)."*

So your problem is that skype is recording from the monitor source of your sound card and not from the microphone. To solve this install `pavucontrol`:

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

then launch it and go to the *Recording tab*. Now initiate a test call in Skype. Skype will show up in the recording tab and it is likely recording from a monitor, like in this screenshot:

[image: Skype recording from monitor source]

Change it to record from your proper input source, e.g. see this screenshot:

[image: Skype recording from a correct source]

Pulseaudio should remember your choice, so next time you won't have to go into `pavucontrol`.

Comment: Yay, that was it! I did have pavucontrol, but didn't check settings while recording (which is when that setting is visible) ... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try re-intsalling your microphone driver. I had the similar problem. When I installed new microphone driver my problem was gone...